# Symbolic link to a view in Kohana

Tags: php, kohana

I'm using an HTML template, where every single data object is presented in a box (every news, article etc.). I assumed I will possibly replace the template in the future, so I decided to create symbolic-linked views to the view 'box', which is included in the main template.
These unix filesystem symbolic links are called 'news', 'article' etc. 
Is there any way to implement it in Kohana or do you know any other way to solve the problem?

Comment: Can you show some code of your template? I don't understand your question completely. And which version of Kohana do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Kohana should treat symbolic links as if they were normal files.

If they are not behaving that way, check your webserver config.
Apache often does not follow symbolic links by default.